# How to break an alpha numeric string using C#?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010

I have this string `2014CCB2016123` which is actually roll number of the students and I want to break that string in its original format(using C#) that is `2014-CCB-2016-123`. Please let me know how I can do it in C#?

---

### EDIT

Here is what I've tried:

```
if(Char.IsLetter(abc[i])) 
{ 
   switch(abc[i].ToString().ToLower()) 
   { 
       case "C": 
       case "B": //This is number 2! 
       break; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: and what are the rules there; split at 4/3/4/3? what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I've to follow this rule.

Comment: understood; so again, what have you tried?

Comment: Here is what I've tried: if(Char.IsLetter(abc[i]))
                {
                    switch(abc[i].ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                         case "C":
                          
                        case "B":
                         //This is number 2!
                         break;


      }
                
            }

Comment: that suggests I have misunderstood the question, then; what has "C" / "B" got to do with "number 2" ?

Comment: "C" is repeated in the string so I've checked it at once.

Comment: but "C" is also repeated in the output... not sure why you need to check for it... can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string splitstr = "2014CCB2016123";
string splitstrSplited= splitstr.Substring(0, 4) + "-" + splitstr.Substring(4, 3) + "-" + splitstr.Substring(7, 4) + "-" + splitstr.Substring(11);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `string.join` also.

```
string splitstrSplited = string.Join("-", new string[] { splitstr.Substring(0, 4), splitstr.Substring(4, 3), splitstr.Substring(7, 4), splitstr.Substring(11) });
```